# Hair children aren't showing in particle edit mode

Tags: particles, 3d-view, hair

Can't display children hair from **particle edit mode** as it is shown on this famous video at 1:40:
[Blender Hair Tutorial Part 1 (styling the hair)](https://youtu.be/KpVyTc_72z0?t=100)

I have to go back to the **object mode** so the additionals spline appears.

**Is there any way to display the extra hair directly while editing?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable **the children option in the top right corner of the window** before painting your strands, then the preview is working:

[image]